# Spring Boot Jpa Delete not working for second entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot with Hibernate. I have an entity parent having relationship with two different child (child1 and child2) entities. I have two records in DB where first record, parent with child1 and second record, parent with chid2. At any point one parent cannot have both child1 and child2 in my case. I am trying to delete parent records using list of parent Ids, expecting both parent and child to get deleted. But only for first Id, I could see delete statement for both parent and child1 but for the second Id, it tries to delete parent without deleting child2 and it throws constraint violation error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "parent" violates foreign key constraint "child2_parent_FK" on table "child2"


Parent.java

@Entity
@Table(schema = "test", name = "parent")
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", 
    orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Child1> child1 = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", 
    orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Child2> child2 = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}

Child1.java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "test", name = "child1")
public class Child1 {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_functional_id", nullable = false)
   private Parent parent;
   ...
}

Child2.java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "test", name = "child2")
public class Child2 {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_functional_id", nullable = false)
   private Parent parent;
   ...
}
```

Created two Parent records, first parent with child1 and another parent with child2. Using below code to delete Parent records.

```
parentIds.stream().forEach(id -> parentRepository.findById(id)
    .ifPresent(parent -> parentRepository.delete(parent)));
```

But I could see for first Id it generates delete statement for both Parent and child1 and for second Id where it have relationship with child2, it tries to delete only Parent and throws above error. I tried passing Id that has child2 first, in this case it works for first Id and throws error for second one that has relationship with child1.

I tried with @Transactional but still same error.

### Edit

If I pass one id in first request and another id in another request, it gets deleted. Issue occurs if I pass two Ids in same request and iterate the Ids and delete one by one.

Comment: does following work: `ifPresent(parent -> {parentRepository.delete(parent); parentRepository.flush();})`?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov : I tried below, but still getting same error.                                 
   `parentIds.stream().forEach(id -> parentRepository.findById(id).ifPresent(parent-> {
          parent.getchild1().clear();
          parent.getchild2().clear();
          parentRepository.delete(parent);
          parentRepository.flush();
        }));`

Comment: Did you try without `stream`? I have a vague memory of something like this being solved with an enhanced for loop (implying you are only using `forEach`), but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @JettoMartínez : I tried like below also, but still same issue for second record, though it deletes the first one. `for (String id : ids) {
      final var entity = parentRepository.findById(id);
      if (entity.isPresent()) {
        final var parent= entity.get();
        parent.getchild1().clear(); parent.getchild2().clear(); parentRepository.delete(parent);           parentRepository.flush(); }}`

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing the same as you did and it worked with no issues. Just make sure the data is correctly inserted into the database, for example, make sure the two child table's records reference different parent entities, so if the first one deletes the parent the other parent record doesn't get deleted.

Comment: can you please share your code ?

Comment: You tried deleting by iterating array of Id's?

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/Biggestprime/test-stackoverflow